# Angular Strap data-minute-step set dynamic

Tags: angularjs, timepicker

I tried to set up `data-minute-step={{somevalue}}` but if I change the value, it doesn't update the picker. Can I do something about it?

Example:

```
<input type="number" ng-model="stepSize">    
<input bs-timepicker data-minute-step="{{stepSize}}">
```

This is what I have:

```
<input id="timetable.amountPerLeson" 
       class="form-control" 
       type="number" 
       step="15" 
       placeholder="45 min"
       ng-model="durationStep">

<input id="timetable.start" 
       class="form-control" 
       type="text" 
       placeholder="date"
       ng-model="slot.startHour"
       bs-timepicker 
       data-time-format="HH:mm" 
       data-length="1" 
       data-minute-step="{{durationStep}}"
       data-arrow-behavior="picker" 
       ng-show="slot.name === 'Hours'" >
```

Comment: I deleted my answer again, but can you tell what happen if you just print `{{ stepSize }}` (Not as attribute) anywhere in the view, and update the input - does it also render in the view?

Comment: Yes, it renders. I mean it gets updated in DOM.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look on the [source code](https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/blob/master/src/timepicker/timepicker.js) and it doesn't seem to watch changes on the attributes - They are evaluated only once, so that's why chaning the `data-minute-step` via input doens't work.

The workaround I can suggest is to force rendering the timepicker element, when you update the minutes steps:

```
<input id="timetable.amountPerLeson" class="form-control" type="number" step="15" placeholder="45 min"
       ng-model="durationStep" ng-change="minutesUpdated()">

 <input id="timetable.start" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="date"
       ng-model="slot.startHour"
       bs-timepicker data-time-format="HH:mm" data-length="1" ng-attr-data-minute-step="{{durationStep}}"
       data-arrow-behavior="picker" ng-show="slot.name === 'Hours'" ng-if="!renderTimePicker">
```

Add the render function to the controller (Make sure you inject `$timeout`):

```
$scope.minutesUpdated = function() {
    $scope.renderTimePicker = true;
    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.renderTimePicker = false;
    });
};
```

Changing the minutes step from the view will trigger the `$scope.minutesUpdated()` function, it will remove the timepicker from the view (Because I added `ng-if="!renderTimePicker"` to the element), and bring it back again after the view has rendered (By resetting `$scope.renderTimePicker = false;` inside the `$timeout`).

Please note that I changed the `data-minute-step` to `ng-attr-data-minute-step`  because I think it will make it work.